# AuthSession in react-native (expo) doesnt return to app Android

Tags: react-native, expo

I have an application written in react Native code. I have component with this function:

```
handleLogin = async () => {
    let redirectUrl = AuthSession.getRedirectUrl();
    let results = await AuthSession.startAsync({
        authUrl: `https://exampleurl.com/?uid=${CLIENT_ID}&redirect_uri=${encodeURIComponent(redirectUrl)}`
    });

    if (results.type !== 'success') {
        this.setState({ didError: true });
    } else {

        if(results.params.token != undefined) {
            let user = {
                name: results.params.uname,
                surname: results.params.surname,
                token: results.params.token
            }
            this.setState({ userInfo: user});
            this.props.loginUser(this.state.userInfo);
        }
    }
};
```

The problem is that when I run them in Expo it works perfect, open propriate URL, I log in and then server in success return me to redirect_uri and app hide webapp modal and show what I need.

BUT when I export app to android and install this apk in my phone, it still works perfect, on click open webview, I log in as user and it return. But it stays at step "Return to app". It never return to app. I also has defined schema in my app.json:

```
    {
  "expo": {
    "name": "MyNewApp",
    "slug": "MyNewApp",
    "privacy": "public",
    "sdkVersion": "32.0.0",
    "platforms": [
      "ios",
      "android"
    ],
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "scheme": "MyNewApp",
    "updates": {
      "fallbackToCacheTimeout": 0
    },
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.roche.mynewapp",
      "supportsTablet": true
    },
    "android": {
      "package": "com.roche.mynewapp"
    }
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I tried set redirect uri as `encodeURIComponent('MyNewApp://')` to use as my schema defined but also without success.

Comment: any solution ??

Comment: I  removed  expo and switch to default React stuffs :)

Comment: Even I did like that atlast :P

Answer (score 0):

The `scheme` in `app.json` must be your `android.package` name.

So in your case `scheme: "com.roche.mynewapp"`

This worked for me. For more details follow the **Expo Docmentation** https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/app-auth/#appauthoauthredirect